# Running code isn't providing any output

Tags: python, function, read-eval-print-loop

I have a program that, simplified, looks like this:

```
def listAssign(lst,index,item):
    """Assigns item item to list lst at index index, returns modified list."""
    lst[index] = item
    return lst

def listInsert(lst,index,item):
    """Inserts item item to list lst at index index, returns modified list."""
    lst.insert(index.item)
    return lst

# ...

def listSurgery(lst,indices,f,*extraArgs):
    """Performs operation f on list lst at depth at indices indices, returns modified list."""
    parent = lst
    for index in indices[:-1]:
        parent = parent[index]
    parent = f(parent,indices[-1],*extraArgs)
    return listSurgery(lst,indices[:-1],listAssign,parent)

# ...

def parseStringToList(s):
    """Takes in a user-input string, and converts it into a list to be passed into parseListToExpr."""
    for c in s[:]: # Removes extra spaces from beginning of string
        if c == ' ':
            s = s[1:]
        else:
            break
    for c in s[::-1]: # Removes spaces from end of string
        if c == ' ':
            s = s[:-1]
        else:
            break
    l = [] # List to build from string; built by serially appending stuff as it comes up
    b = True # Bool for whether the parser is experiencing spaces (supposed to be True if last character processed was a space)
    t = False # Bool for whether the parser is experiencing a string of non-alphanumeric characters (supposed to be True if last character was a non-alphanumeric character)
    lvl = 0 # Keeps track of depth at which operations are supposed to be occurring
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ': # If the character is a space, do nothing, but make sure that it's documented that the last character processed was a space
            b = True
        elif c == '(' or c == '[': # If the character is an opening parenthesis, add a new level of depth to the list, by appending another list to the lowest level and incrementing lvl
            l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),listInsert,[])
            lvl += 1
            if c == '[': # ] (left here for overzealous parsers) If the bracket is square, also append a comma as the first element of the appended list
                l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),listInsert,',')
        elif c == ')' or c == ']': # If it's a closing parenthesis, make it stop paying attention to the list it's working on
            lvl -= 1
        elif c == ',': # If it's a comma, then append it to the list as a separate element and start a new string to append characters to
            l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),lambda x,y,z:listAssign(x,y,x[y]+z),[',',''])
        elif not c.alnum(): # If it's non-alphanumeric and not any of the above, then append it to string that it's working on if it's a non-alphanumeric string
            if not t: # If the string that it's working on isn't non-alphanumeric, then finish working on that string and append a new string to work on
                l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),listInsert,'')
            l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),lambda x,y,z:listAssign(x,y,x[y]+z),c)
            t = True
        else: # If the character is alphanumeric, append it to the string it's working on
            assert c.isalnum()
            if b or t: # If the string it's working on isn't alphanumeric or doesn't exist, append a new string
                l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),listInsert,'')
                b, t = False, False
            l = listSurgery(l,[-1]*(lvl+1),lambda x,y,z:listAssign(x,y,x[y]+z),c)
    return l

# ...

cmds = {
        'help':"List the available functions.",
        'quit':"Quit this application.",
        'exit':"Exit this application (exactly the same thing)."
        }

print "MAT (Michael's Analysis Tool), version 0.0.0"

op = '' # Declare string to use for input
while op != 'exit' and op != 'quit': # Keep a REPL unless the user types "exit" or "quit", in which case exit
    op = raw_input("> ")
    if op == 'help':
        print "The commands available in addition to free evaluation are:"
        for item in cmds:
            print ' ', item + ":", cmds[item]
    elif op == 'quit' or 'exit':
        pass
    else:
        print str(parseStringToList(op))
```

When I use `help`, `quit`, or `exit` as a command, it comes out fine.  But when I give it any other kind of input like `1 + 1 = 2` (which should elicit `['1','+','1','=','2']`) or `This is a sentence.` (which should elicit `['This','is','a','sentence','.']`, it doesn't print anything, just asks for more input. (That is, it's functionally equivalent to the last line of this program getting replaced with `continue`.) And I don't understand why. `parseStringToList` is defined in a very straightforward manner. It should at *least* return `[]`, the original value of the variable it returns. But instead it doesn't print anything. Why? (I'll try more thorough debugging tomorrow, but so far it's eluded my efforts.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
elif op == 'quit' or 'exit':
```

to this

```
elif op == 'quit' or op == 'exit':
```

Comment: (I don't have access to the code right now.) I noticed that, but then I remembered that it's been working exactly like I wanted it to: if I typed `help`, it printed out the help; if I typed `quit` or `exit`, it quit/exited. So I assumed that this was actually a thing you could do in Python, and I just hadn't heard about it until now. Thank you!

Comment: Even better: `elif op in {'quit', 'exit'}:`